# Redraw titlebar after setting dark mode in Windows

Tags: c, winapi

I am using the following library call to change the window to dark mode:

```cpp
BOOL dark = TRUE;
DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, &dark, sizeof(dark));
```

This works, with a small caveat. The title bar doesn't update until some additional event happens, like maximizing, losing focus, resizing, etc. (but not moving the window).

I have tried `UpdateWindow` and a huge number of combinations of flags on `RedrawWindow` with no luck. How can I force the title bar to redraw?

**Edit** I was able to force the reset by programmatically resizing the window, then resetting it to the previous size. But that seems like a terrible method. There must be a proper solution.

Comment: does this helps? [invalidating-non-client-areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819937/invalidating-non-client-areas)

Comment: Did you try the answer that's not accepted, i.e. calling [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos)?

Comment: Yes, that didn;t work either

Comment: The only way we've found to do this is by using an undocumented API. Unfortunately Microsoft have not properly finished or documented their Dark Mode API.

Comment: @JonathanPotter can you please point out which undocumented API did you use to achieve this? I am facing a similar issue and haven't found a solution yet.